# How do I make Unity remember which applications are in the launcher?

Tags: 11.04, unity

When i log out and then log in again, the applications shown in Unity launcher are the default applications, neither can i add an application nor can i hide a default application. How to make Unity remember my apps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found the answer: `dconf-tools` and `libdconf0` were not installed, so unity couldn't remember settings.

Use Software Center or `apt-get` to install:

- [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools)
- [libdconf0](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libdconf0)

Comment: This was the problem, without these packages it cannot save settings.

Comment: Oops, sorry! Only `dconf-tools` is optional. `libdconf0` is part of the default installation and I see your symptoms when it's removed.

Comment: having the same issue. None of the solutions work. i'll go back to 11.04. Unity drives me insane and effin' sucks. arrgggggg

Answer (score 3):

You may have a bug. I simply right click on the items in the launcher to pin or unpin them.

Comment: it works indeed for out-of-the-box applications like terminal, shotwell, etc. However, you can reproduce the problem if you, e.g. launch Eclipse application from unpacked tar-package (not from deb-package installation). Also you will face the problem that the application icon is not found.

Comment: you have to create a desktop file for this application. unity launcher just remembers desktop files, not applications

Comment: I see. It would natural and user-friendly though, if in such a case those files could be created on-fly when "Keep in Launcher" is selected.

Comment: Yes it would be :) File this as a bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/ :)

Answer (score 3):

For those who're looking for a solution to **make Unity remember settings after a GNOME3 update and reverting back to Unity**, I have a solution which uses the above Q&A as a start.

If you've installed `dconf-tools` and `libdconf0`, you can run into a problem which is:

- when you try editing Unity's Launcher settings with `sudo dconf-editor`, you can find the right values under desktop > unity > launcher, but it seems to be read-only;
- when you try to use use gsettings, it says

> GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend. Your
>   settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

then **don't give up**, you're only one step away from solving the problem!

This solution is quite fun; you will have to re-add the gnome3 team repo and install a package from there:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dconf-gsettings-backend
```

*[I don't really know why this works, but it seems installing GNOME3 stuff messes up the GSettings backends so much that it can't be repaired by only installing dconf-tools and libdconf0.]*

You can check whether the settings are writeable by running

```
gsettings writable com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

If everything is fine then it returns true and after a logout/login Unity will remember the settings.

Comment: it does return true, but only after : "GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications."