# Launcher Icons Revert to Default Upon Login

Tags: unity, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i make Unity remember which applications are in the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35625/how-do-i-make-unity-remember-which-applications-are-in-the-launcher)

Every time I log in, I get the same default icons despite having removed them and added new ones (by right-clicking on apps like skype and pressing "keep in launcher"). I hope I have explained my problem thoroughly - I am an ubuntun00b. Is this just a bug and is it fixable, or am I missing something here?

Comment: It happens with all applications that you try to keep in launcher or with some like skype and thunderbird?

Comment: With all applications that I try to keep in the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the libdconf0 package. Installing it seems to have done the trick for the filer of [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/774577). You can do this through the Software Center. If it doesn't show up, click the "Show technical items" link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's a silly answer, but it doesn't hurt either: run this command to get sure everything under your profile is of your own:

chown username:username -R *

Maybe there's something somewhere that is from root or was created under root and can't write there.