# Launcher doesn't remember custom icons

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make Unity remember which applications are in the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35625/how-do-i-make-unity-remember-which-applications-are-in-the-launcher)

Okay, on a fresh install of 11.04 unity there are default icons; these inclide libreoffice, ubuntu software center, ubuntu one, etc. When I try to modify these, as in remove them form the launcher or add new ones to the launcher, all is well until I restart my computer or log back in - all my modifications are erased and the the same default sequence remains (libreoffice, ubuntu, software center, ubuntu one).

During sessions I added applications to the launcher, for example banshee and pidgin, by clicking and dragging. I made sure the option "keep in launcher" was checked for each app. Also I removed firefox and ubuntu one from the launcher, and rearranged applications. Yet every time I log out or reboot my computer, the launcher is resetted to its default settings. Firefox and ubuntu one, are back in the launcher; banshee and pidgin are gone and the order of the applications on the launcher are restored.

What can be possibly be the problem? Furthermore I could not add chrome to the launcher by dragging. I found a thread on [Bug 771172](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/771172) - Custom Unity Launcher entries not from.local/share/applications.

I tried the same by moving google-chrome.desktop to /usr/share/applications , and then it DID work, and I could add google-chrome on the launcher by dragging. Yet still when I rebooted, the settings of the launcher were restored and google-chrome removed. I have got no idea what the origin of the problem could be. I searched the internet and the forums intensively, but I haven't found anyone with the same problem yet.

Comment: There's two of us apparently: I do have the same problem!