# how to make changes to launcher in unity permanent?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make Unity remember which applications are in the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35625/how-do-i-make-unity-remember-which-applications-are-in-the-launcher)

i spent now a couple of hours reading and trying. i went through the whole faq here, but couldn't find any help for my problem.

i'm running ubuntu 11.04 for a few days, now.

whenever i add or remove something to the launcher - drag and drop a .desktop file or by clicking on "keep in launcher" to remove the tick - the next time i log in all these changes are gone!

config for unity always resets to the default on every log-in.

Comment: thanks Jorge. My problem was the same has he already reported a while ago. Installing libdconf0 solved it.