# Unity application launchers are disappeared

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

Once I'm adding application launcher onto unity dock I expect it will be there as long as I want, but after the system restarted they're just disappeared.

What may cause the problem or what should I do to achieve my launchers to be in there?

Sultan

Comment: Have you right-clicked on the launcher and ticked "keep in dock"?

Comment: @N.N. Yes I did, but the same happens

Comment: I also want to get rid off LibreOffice launchers and they return back on restart

Comment: Maybe you have this problem? http://askubuntu.com/questions/35625/how-do-i-make-unity-remember-which-applications-are-in-the-launcher/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you add a launcher! Run a application and right click on icon and select keep in  launcher. If you are doing right but getting problem then

```
unity --reset
```

Now add launcher according above process, restart and check.

Comment: Not affected...

Comment: reinstall unity using synaptic manager

Answer (score 0):

**Click on the link below to open in the software center and see if it is installed:**

[libdconf0](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libdconf0)

Comment: Yes it is installed