# Unity Launcher Does Not Remember Favorites

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I have already looked at the [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35625/how-do-i-make-unity-remember-which-applications-are-in-the-launcher/), but none of the solutions there worked for me. Basically, I can edit and remove icons just fine when I am in a session, but the next time I am logged in, they are reset to the default.

Even more perplexing is this. If I start dconf-editor, and navigate to desktop>unity>launcher, it shows the favorites that are supposed to be there, yet the default ones are still in the Launcher.

I have already tried `sudo apt-get purge unity` and then `sudo apt-get install unity` from a GNOME session, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Edit:
I also tried running `gksudo dconf-editor` to run the program with elevated privileges. Again I navigated to desktop>unity>launcher. This time the default string was there, but when I tried to edit it, it would not change to what I typed.

Comment: Do you use Natty? This is very weird, though. Try `unity --reset`.

Comment: I have tried `unity --reset`. However, when I do that, the command always seems  to halt at a certain part. I'm not sure at what part though. I'll try running it and letting it sit for an extended period of time and then I'll try it with elevated privileges.

Comment: Did you try this one? http://askubuntu.com/questions/35625/how-do-i-make-unity-remember-which-applications-are-in-the-launcher/

Comment: @Jorge Yes I have.

Comment: When I try `sudo unity --reset`, it doesn't like that. Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/mycrRQXt.
When I just do `unity --reset` it gets to a certain point, then hangs. Here is the output for that: http://pastebin.com/sMjikhwb

Comment: Actually `unity --reset` got a little further. I'm just gonna let it sit for a while.

Comment: This sounds like a bug report and not really a question. You seem willing to spend some time working on the problem, and already have. It is much more useful (to you too) if you report bugs on launchpad.net. It's much more suitable for these kinds of issues and the developers will be able to provide you with exact steps to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Here again to notify that after the installation of dconf-tools, libdconf-dbus-1-0, libdconf0 everything goes well:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools libdconf0 libdconf-dbus-1-0
```

I found this on a bug submitted for empathy that did not save the settings.

Comment: I've done this but still am having problems. During `unity --reset` I get this error message several times: `GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend. Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.`

Comment: **UPDATE**: I had to uninstall and then install libdconf0 in order to get my panel to start saving icons.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also get the error message

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend. Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

when you do `gsettings monitor com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites`?

It would be a bug similar to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/620733 then, and you could solve it by installing dconf, libdconf0, and libdconf-dbus-1-0 package

At least that’s what worked for me, when my launcher didn’t remember the favorites.

Comment: I installed those packages and restarted, but when I ran `gsettings monitor com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites` it showed the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a step before reinstalling dconf-tools, libdconf0, libdconf-dbus-1-0, removing them completly with

```
sudo apt-get remove dconf-tools libdconf0 libdconf-dbus-1-0
```

Comment: Ok....everything was looking fine until I launched dconf. Result: it crashes with the following error

** ERROR **: dconf.vala:96: unknown command
aborting...